# App not launching and get crashed when using the imagebutton in android

Tags: android

I  just started to develop my first application in android.

Here i used a image button.

But when i try to run my app in device it is not launching a an errors are showing in the log cat.

can any one please help me in how to resolve this error.Thanks in advance.Hoping for your help.

This is the code i used:

```
ArraysActivity.java

package com.me.array;
//import com.sweans.pus.SingleListItem;

//import com.sweans.pus.SecondScreen;


//import com.me.array.R;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

public class ArraysActivity extends Activity {
        ListView listView;
         private  ImageButton mybtn;
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

        String[] sujith =new String[]{ "The-Birth", "Menu", "Album",
                        "Events", "Blog", "Press", "Reservation", "MONOMANIA",
                        "Contact" };
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mybtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgbtn);
        mybtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ZActivity.class);
                startActivity(nextScreen);
            }
        });




         listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, sujith);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
           //   Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
              // startActivity(new Intent(action));
                 if(position == 0){
                 Intent i = new Intent(ArraysActivity.this, SingleListItem.class);

                 // passing variable
                 i.putExtra("my.package.dataToPass","new");
          //i.putExtra( "int",position);

                 startActivity(i);
                 }
                 else   if(position == 1){
                         Intent i = new Intent(ArraysActivity.this, ListSample.class);

                startActivity(i);
                         }

                 else   if(position == 2){
                         Intent i = new Intent(ArraysActivity.this, MyGridView.class);

                startActivity(i);
                         }
                else    if(position == 4){
                         Intent i = new Intent(ArraysActivity.this, MessageList.class);

                startActivity(i);
                         }
           }
       });
    }
}

main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <!--  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="278dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/home_page" /> -->

    <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/imgbtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="278dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/home_page"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>


Androidmanifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.me.array"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_andro"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ArraysActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
              <activity android:name=".SingleListItem"></activity>
              <activity android:name=".menu"></activity>
              <activity android:name=".ListSample"></activity>
              <activity android:name=".SeperatedListAdapter"></activity>
              <activity android:name=".MyGridView"></activity>
                 <activity android:name=".Message"></activity>
                    <activity android:name=".MessageList"></activity>
                 <activity android:name=".BaseFeedParser"></activity>
                 <activity android:name=".SeparatedListAdapter"></activity>
                 <activity android:name=".RssHandler"></activity>
                     <activity android:name=".ZActivity"></activity>
    </application>
                        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

The log cat is showing a NPE in line number 36,ie mybtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){.

my log cat is [image]

Comment: Does it still crash if you comment out the block in question (line 36 to 42)?

Comment: @TomDignan how to build clean a android project.Im very sorry for asking this.Im a newbie here.

Comment: @user923370 `Build` > `Clean...` up in the toolbar/menubar.

Comment: give  listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist); before imageButton onclik. After that do clean and compile.

Comment: Can you post the code for your main.xml file?

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that you posted it already

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the anonymous onClikListener, try it like this:

```
mybtn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then, in the end of your source, implement the listener,

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    //do the stuff you want here
}
```

I would replace getApplicationContext() with "this" btw, of course in this version only.

It should work this way, I think.

OR, you might want to try it like this:

```
Context ctx; //define it as class variable
```

In the onCreate:

```
ctx=this;
```

Replace your getApplicationContext() with ctx, I think that is the thing which gives you the NullPointer.